# In Redmine how to add my custom plugin inside Project Menu Bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to add my Plugin inside a project's menu eg. I want to use my plugin as: https://redmine-site/projects/test-project/my-plugin

[Like in this image i want to link my plugin after SPENT TIME in the menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyyzx.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can add link to your custom controller (or any other place) in project menu. use this code in your init.rb

```
menu :project_menu, :plugin_example, { controller: :example, action: :say_hello}, caption: :label_sample, after: :time_entries, :param => :project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the link to your custom controller and add the permissions otherwise its not shown.

```
 permission :performancedetail, { :performance => [:index, :vote] }, :public => true
 menu :project_menu, :performancedetail, { controller: 'performance', action: 'index' }, caption: 'Performance'
```